# Simulink very slow when reading large amount of signals to root level input ports

Tags: matlab, optimization, input, signal-processing, simulink

I'm trying to read structures of timeseries objects into root level input ports in simulink as described [here](http://se.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/importing-structures-of-matlab-timeseries-objects-for-bus-signals-to-a-root-level-input-port.html), however, the model is reading the data extremely slowly.

I basically removed everything and now only have input ports going into terminators, and every time-step (0.01 sampling time) takes around one second.

What is going on here, this can't possibly correct? I should mention that I am reading around 500 signals, each a timeseries object.

Comment: Could you provide [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: how large is your timeseries object that you read per iteration?

Comment: The exemple is provided in the link, you can reproduce it by reading a structure of around 500 time series to a root level input bus( as shown in the link) I'm using the fixed variable discrete step solver. The times series consist of around 2000 samples, the fundamental sampling rate is 0.01s.

Comment: @TestCase: Such a description does not help. If I would follow it and run it, I would know nothing. Is it "extremely slow"? What is extremely slow? Do I get a different performance because of a different PC, Simulink-Version or Matab-Version?